# ASP.NET MVC 5 view can't access model properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

When I try to use `@Model.property`, none of the properties that are in my ViewModel show up, so I can't select or display anything. I've searched on Google, and read that a restart of Visual Studio would help but it didn't. I've rebuilt the solution, etc. as well, but nothing seems to help. What gives?

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult GebruikersList()
{
    List<Gebruiker> gebruikers = db.Gebruikers.ToList();
    //List<GebruikerModel> gebruikersVM = Mapper.Map<List<Gebruiker>, List<GebruikerModel>>(gebruikers);

    GebruikerModel singleUser = Mapper.Map<Gebruiker, GebruikerModel>(db.Gebruikers.FirstOrDefault());

    return View(singleUser);
}
```

**View:**

```
@model alina1617.Models.GebruikerModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "GebruikersListTest";
}

<h2>GebruikersList</h2>


<p>
    @Model.
</p>
```

**ViewModel:**

```
public class GebruikerModel
{
    String Gebruikersnaam { get; set; }
    String Wachtwoord { get; set; }

    // Om automapper automatisch te laten converteren simpelweg klassenaam (FaculteitModel) + property (Naam) gebruiken
    String FaculteitModelNaam { get; set; }
    String InstellingModelMNaam { get; set; }

}

public class FaculteitModel
{
    String Naam { get; set; }
}                                                                                     

public class InstellingModel
{
    String naam { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your model properties are public you are able to access them within the view. Hope this helps.

```
public class GebruikerModel
{
    public String Gebruikersnaam { get; set; }
    public String Wachtwoord { get; set; }

    // Om automapper automatisch te laten converteren simpelweg klassenaam (FaculteitModel) + property (Naam) gebruiken
    public String FaculteitModelNaam { get; set; }
    public String InstellingModelMNaam { get; set; }

}

    public class FaculteitModel
    {
        public String Naam { get; set; }
    }                                                                                     

    public class InstellingModel
    {
        public String naam { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: You've solved another question I had as well (was trying to use automappers 'Isconfiguartionvalid" method and it wasn't working, but this was the cause of that as well. Thanks! Will accept when i'm able to

Comment: Great, it's an easy mistake to make and one I have made as well. Hopefully it makes sense too now!